# Eclipse shows different version of sqlite database in project than what my code reads

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I made a few changes in the sqlite database in my project using a JDBC connection. However, once I exported the project as a runnable jar, an older (abt. a week ago) version of the database was exported.

I then checked the database directly, copying it and pasting it into an sqlite file viewer, and the database itself shows up in its week-old form in the project view, although my code reads a new version with all of the new entries and changes.

How can I make it show and export the new version? Thanks a lot in advance!